# Sound over network (Windows, Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, audio, android

I have 2 computers with windows and a server with Ubuntu (also an android phone). I want to take all sounds form these devices and play it only on one of them.

e.g. I'm watching a movie on my computer > I want all the sounds to be played on ubuntu server with 5.1 speakers.
I'm playing a game and watching a tv show > I want to play them on windows computer with headphones attached.

**tl;dr I want to combine sound output from these devices (win, ubuntu, android) and play it on one of their attached headphones/speakers**

Tried http://soundseeder.com/, but you can't play from windows.

*Partial solutions or just ideas welcome*